# Scroll only when mouse over

Tags: windows, perl, tk-toolkit, perltk

I am trying to provide scrolling behaviour on a GUI developed using Perl TK.

What I would like to achieve is, when the mouse is over a widget such as a `Scrolled` containing a `ListBox`, the user should be able to scroll up and down using the mouse wheel. The mouse counts as being over the widget if it is over the widget itself **or** the scrollbars at the sides of the widget. In over words, if the mouse is anywhere over the `Scrolled` and not just the `ListBox`.

I have included an example below that works when the mouse is over the `ListBox` but it does not work if it is just outside the `ListBox` but it is still on the `Scrolled`.

It is worth noting, for the mouse wheel support, this is Windows specific on my example.

Example script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $mainWindow = new MainWindow;

my $lb = $mainWindow->Scrolled("Listbox", -scrollbars => "osoe")->pack;

$lb->insert('end', qw/red blue yellow green orange/);
$lb->insert('end', qw/red blue yellow green orange/);
$lb->insert('end', qw/red blue yellow green orange/);
$lb->insert('end', qw/red blue yellow green orange/);
$lb->insert('end', qw/red blue yellow green orange/);

my $lbCanScroll = 0;
$mainWindow->bind('<MouseWheel>' => [sub{ if($lbCanScroll) { $lb->yview('scroll', -($_[1] / 120) * 3, 'units'); } }, Ev('D')]);
$lb->bind('<Leave>' => sub{$lbCanScroll = 0});
$lb->bind('<Enter>' => sub{$lbCanScroll = 1});

MainLoop;
```

---

Whilst I have posted what I will call a temporary solution, it would be nice to know if there was a more reusable way to achieve this.

Comment: What is interesting is that on unix, (ubuntu 18.04) you can comment out the `$mainWindow->bind('<MouseWheel>' => [sub{ if($lbCanScroll) { $lb->yview('scroll', -($_[1] / 120) * 3, 'units'); } }, Ev('D')]);` part while keeping the scrolling behaviour, so it must be another binding doing it.

Comment: @saudic Thanks for the reply. That is strange as the above code is literally the whole program. It is possible I am using a very old version of Perl TK that might not have supported this behaviour (not my choice or I would update it) or it might just behave differently on windows to Linux. Either way thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary solution, I can put it in a wrapper object that stores only that one component. This allows me to bind to the `Enter` and `Leave` events on that object. It looks a bit like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $mainWindow = new MainWindow;

my $lbHolder = $mainWindow->Pane()->pack;

my $lb = $lbHolder->Scrolled("Listbox", -scrollbars => "osoe")->pack;

$lb->insert('end', qw/red blue yellow green orange/);
$lb->insert('end', qw/red blue yellow green orange/);
$lb->insert('end', qw/red blue yellow green orange/);
$lb->insert('end', qw/red blue yellow green orange/);
$lb->insert('end', qw/red blue yellow green orange/);

my $lbCanScroll = 0;
$mainWindow->bind('<MouseWheel>' => [sub{ if($lbCanScroll) { $lb->yview('scroll', -($_[1] / 120) * 3, 'units'); } }, Ev('D')]);
$lbHolder->bind('<Leave>' => sub{$lbCanScroll = 0});
$lbHolder->bind('<Enter>' => sub{$lbCanScroll = 1});

MainLoop;
```